# Zipping two lists into a single list of objects rather than a list of tuples?

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

```
val l1 = List(1, 2, 3)
val l2 = List('a', 'b', 'c')

val tupleList = l1.zip(l2)
// List((1,a), (2,b), (3,c))

val objectList = l1.zip(l2).map(tuple => new MyObject(tuple._1, tuple._2))
// List(MyObject@7e1a1da6, MyObject@5f7f2382, MyObject@407cf41)
```

After writing this code, I feel like the `map(tuple => new MyObject(tuple._1, tuple._2))` part looks a little dirty for two reasons:

1. I shouldn't be creating the tuples just to discard them in favor of `MyObject`. Why not just zip `l1` and `l2` into a list of `MyObject` in the first place?
2. `tuple._1` and `tuple._2` don't have any semantics. It can take some mental gymnastics to make sure I'm giving the `Int` as the first parameter and the `Char` as the second.

Is it possible to zip two Lists into my own object?

How can I make the `MyObject` construction above more semantically clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scala> case class Foo(i: Int, c: Char)
defined class Foo

scala> val f = Foo.apply _
f: (Int, Char) => Foo = <function2>

scala> (l1, l2).zipped map f
res12: List[Foo] = List(Foo(1,a), Foo(2,b), Foo(3,c))
```

More info, since someone didn't get what I meant, here's what this map looks like:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/runtime/Tuple2Zipped.scala#L35

Comment: Did not downvote, but I also didn't care to look how `zipped` worked internally. Should have done that. +1

Comment: @Kigyo s/o on SO pointed out Tuple2Zipped once and then I learned to put the parens the right way. It's the rare class no one complains about.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a self made implementation for your problem, you can do something similar to what I did below. (wasted my time with)

There is already one implemented method to do that, which is described in @som-snytt 's answer.

An example implementation for your problem, which does not create intermediate tuples.

```
def createObjects[A,B,C](func: (A,B) => C)(l1: List[A], l2: List[B]) = {
  val resultBuffer = new ListBuffer[C]
  @tailrec
  def loop(l1: List[A], l2: List[B]): Unit = l1 match {
    case head :: tail if l2.headOption.isDefined => {
      resultBuffer += func(l1.head, l2.head)
      loop(l1.tail, l2.tail)
    }
    case Nil =>
  }

  loop(l1, l2)
  resultBuffer.result
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
createObjects(MyObject)(l1, l2)
```

`createObjects(MyObject)(l1, l2)` only works if `MyObject` is a case class or has an apply method.

In the other case you can do one of the following:

```
createObjects[Int, Char, MyObject](new MyObject(_,_))(l1, l2)
createObjects((i: Int, c: Char) => new MyObject(i,c))(l1, l2)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect. `(l1, l2).zipped.map(whatever)` won't create any tuples (apart from the obvious one).

Comment: Just looked at the implementation. Definitely good to know. I never came across that.

Comment: Well, I'm still learning. Wrong statements should be corrected :)

Comment: FWIW, I downvoted because "you can see how wrong the other answers are" (or however you put it) kind of asked for correction. Purely (or puerilely) in the name of science, of course. I've learned so much from @TravisBrown who has downvoted me when I wasn't helpful.

Comment: You might consider reversing your param lists so you can `createObjects(l1,l2) { (i,c) => i+c }`. (Not sure a custom, less-general solution is to be encouraged. Most people ask for the idiom.)

Comment: I said that other answers are relying on creating tuples, nothing more. The other 2 answers used zip and I imagined yours to behave the same (which was obviously wrong). If offer my apologies to anyone who felt insulted. Regarding your last suggestion: I thought it might be nice for having a factory method with currying, where the function is already set up and then use it with different lists.

Comment: Right, I see your curried idea. I was kind of pulling your leg by misquoting you.

Comment: Don't worry. Your comments motivate me to explain myself better in the future. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A slightly cleaner version using pattern matching would help with #2:

```
val objectList = (l1 zip l2).map { case (a, b) => new MyObject(a,b) }
```

A more extreme version would be to use a factory method on a companion class that turned the tuple into an instance of MyClass.

```
object MyClass {
  def make(t: (Int, Char)) = new MyClass(t._1, t._2)
}

val objs = (l1 zip l2).map(MyClass.make)
```

You could even get fancier by making the companion object a function to further reduce the clutter:

```
object MyClass extends (Tuple2[Int, Char] => MyClass) {
  def apply(t: (Int, Char)) = new MyClass(t._1, t._2)
}

val objs = (l1 zip l2).map(MyClass)
```